# Data Access Layer and Business Objects

Tags: java, sql, database

This is my first cut at separating the data access layer out of my very old spaghetti codebase.

I have tried to keep this as simple as possible, it is for a small project, so I am not really interested in learning Spring or Hibernate or other framework, and I don't mind writing a bit of SQL.

I basically have a 1-to-1 relation of database table to business object.

This is the Data Access Layer

```
package dataaccesslayer;

import dbutils.handlers.IgnoreUnderscoreBeanHandler;
import dbutils.handlers.IgnoreUnderscoreBeanListHandler;
import racemanager.businessobjects.Progression;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
import shared.SLDbHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

public class DalProgression {

    private static final String SQL_SELECT_ONE =
            "   SELECT * "
                    + "   FROM progressions "
                    + "  WHERE id=? ";


    private static final String SQL_SELECT_ALL =
            "   SELECT * "
                    + "   FROM progressions "
                    + "  ORDER BY name ASC ";


    public static Progression selectOne(int id) {
        QueryRunner qr;
        Progression progression;

        try {
            qr = new QueryRunner(SLDbHelper.getInstance().getDataSource());
            progression = qr.query(SQL_SELECT_ONE, new IgnoreUnderscoreBeanHandler<Progression>(Progression.class), id);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        return progression;
    }


    public static List<Progression> selectAll() {
        QueryRunner qr;
        List<Progression> progressions;

        try {
            qr = new QueryRunner(SLDbHelper.getInstance().getDataSource());
            progressions = qr.query(SQL_SELECT_ALL, new IgnoreUnderscoreBeanListHandler<Progression>(Progression.class));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        return progressions;
    }

}
```

This is the related Business Object

```
package businessobjects;

import java.util.Date;

public class Progression {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date modified;
    private Date created;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(Date modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getName();
    }

}
```

Usage example

```
int id = 10;
Progression p = DalProgression.selectOne(id);

List<Progressions> pList = DalProgression.selectAll();
```

1. Fire away and shoot holes in my code, so I can improve it.
2. One thing I am not sure about is when I do joins should I have a separate business object for the result, and as such as corresponding data access layer class to perform those queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How small is small?  Hibernate, JPA and so on *would* help you get rid of *a lot* of boilerplate code.

That said.

1. I'd change `selectOne` to `selectById`, similarly for other querying functions, which I'm sure you'll get a lot of, or in general find a good, consistent naming scheme for those functions.
2. Keep in mind that `int` has a particular size if you already have a large legacy database.
3. If possible remove all the `statics` and make `DalProgression` a real object (so you can set and reuse `QueryRunner`/`SLDHelper` and create better tests).
4. Did I mention tests. (Legacy == ) please write tests. It honestly helps so much.
5. In order to do that get rid of the `SLDHelper` singleton,
6. which is not a good name, since it has both an unknown acronym in it (at least to me, otherwise you'd have to explain the name) and additionally `Helper`, which can also mean everything (the acronym goes for `DalProgression` as well, less so since you've mentioned Data Access Layer; still I'd say something like `ProgressionRepository`, `ProgressionStore` or so would be better). If possible I'd just avoid such names.
7. Move the exception conversion into a separate class so you can reuse that, even if you have to create a wrapper for the QueryRunner.
8. You could also just directly return from inside the `try` block and initialise the variables with their values directly, i.e. `try { QueryRunner qr = ...; return qr.query(...); } catch ...`.
9. I'd also create a `SQLRuntimeException` or so in order to `catch` exactly those later instead of grepping for `RuntimeException`.
10. Have a plan for transactions in your API, unless you already have, that is.
11. `IgnoreUnderscoreBeanHandler` is already generic, there are options ([e.g. via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)) to get rid of the class literal argument.
12. Unless you have a specific use for that particular `toString` method I wouldn't use that, rather have something to identify the object in a stacktrace, let's say, the `id` (`"<Progression id=42 name=whatever>"`).
13. Thinking about it, if you have the ID and the timestamps in all business objects, create an abstract base class or an interface to capture that notion.

For the joins, I guess that unless you have extra data in join tables, creating separate business objects isn't necessary.  So I'd imagine it would be easier to understand if you just have methods `List<Foo> selectFooForProgression(Progression)` or `Map<Foo, Progression> selectFoosForProgressions(List<Progression>)` in the `DalProgression` class, basically where you start the join from.

Comment: So for point 3 & 5. You would expect the usage to look like this DalProgression dal = new DalProgression(dataSource); dal.selectById(id);

Comment: Can you please elaborate on point 6, I don't understand what you mean by "a really opaque name"

Comment: Yes, I mean my point of view is oriented along the lines of Spring/DI, so even if you don't use that, I'd rather construct those objects in one place instead of having `static` methods. I'm updating point 6/7.